# A connectedness question

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

$A$ and $B$ are closed sets such that both $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ are connected. It is required to show that $A$ and $B$ are both connected. Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Assume that $A=U\sqcup V$ such that $U$ and $V$ are both open. Reach contradiction.

Comment: That’s what I’m not able to do

Comment: It would be helpful if you could sketch the proof

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=U \cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are disjoint non-empty closed sets. Then $A \cap B= (U\cap B) \cup (V\cap B)$. Since $A\cap B$ is connected this gives $U\cap B =\emptyset$ or $V\cap B =\emptyset$. Suppose $U\cap B =\emptyset$. Then $A \cup B=(V\cup B) \cup U$ which contradicts connectedness of $A\cup B$.